# How to test if powershell command is permitted within a specific Active Directory tree location

Tags: powershell, testing, permissions, active-directory

I have a low privileged user that administers areas of a corporate Active Directory tree using Powershell. I'd like to test that my script can execute an action rather than calling it and barfing. For example I'd like something that will test:

```
If(New-ADGroup -GroupScope Global -Path $OU){
   New-ADGroup -GroupScope Global -Path $OU -Name $GROUP_NAME
}else{
   Write-Host "Ask the administrator to permit"
   Write-Host "$env:USERNAME New-ADGroup privs at $OU"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call it and let it barf. But, just like in real life, you want to catch the barf in an appropriate container.

That's where `try`/`catch` comes in. But PowerShell is a bit odd when it comes to errors. By default, it doesn't stop when an error happens. It just displays it and keeps going. Unless you change that, `try` doesn't see the error. So you also need to tell PowerShell to barf hard when it fails.

That can be done with the `-ErrorAction` parameter, which can be used on any cmdlet.

```
try {
   New-ADGroup -GroupScope Global -Path $OU -Name $GROUP_NAME -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
   Write-Host "Ask the administrator to permit"
   Write-Host "$env:USERNAME New-ADGroup privs at $OU"
}
```

This code assumes that insufficient access is the only reason it will fail. You can examine the error and test if that's the case if you want.

More reading on catching errors in PowerShell: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/09/16/understanding-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell/

And this is helpful too: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/09/handling-errors-the-powershell-way/

Comment: #facepalm - your totally right. function_exists is rather a static check. I'm clearly needing a runtime check and that's exactly what try/catch is for. Thanks for calling out the subtle "oddness" too about error handling.